# Code not working in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

This code working good in mozilla and opera .But not working in IE. Please help.The JavaScript is ok. But in IE 10 only back panel is coming ..

Thank you..

http://codepen.io/syedrafeeq/pen/eCkFt

## CSS 3D FLIP BOX

#### Flipping content to a div (Transitions and 3D Transforms)

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="col_third">
    <div class="hover panel">
      <div class="front">
        <div class="box1">
          <p>Front Side</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="back">
        <div class="box2">
          <p>Back Side</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col_third">
    <div class="hover panel">
      <div class="front">
        <div class="box1">
          <p>Front Side</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="back">
        <div class="box2">
          <p>Back Side</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>

        <div class="col_third end">
        <div class="hover panel">
          <div class="front">
            <div class="box1">
              <p>Front Side</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="back">
            <div class="box2">
              <p>Back Side</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
     </div>

CSS

    body {
    background-color: #ecf0f1;
    margin: 20px;
    font-family: Arial, Tahoma; 
    font-size: 20px; 
    color: #666666; 
    text-align: center; 
}
p { color: #ffffff;  }

/*-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-*/
/* Column Grids */
/*-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-= */

.col_half { width: 49%; }
.col_third { width: 32%; }
.col_fourth { width: 23.5%; }
.col_fifth { width: 18.4%; }
.col_sixth { width: 15%; }
.col_three_fourth { width: 74.5%;}
.col_twothird{ width: 66%;}
.col_half,
.col_third,
.col_twothird,
.col_fourth,
.col_three_fourth,
.col_fifth{
    position: relative;
    display:inline;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 2%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.end { margin-right: 0 !important; }

/*-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=- */
/* Flip Panel */
/*-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=- */

.wrapper{ width: 980px; margin: 0 auto;  background-color: #bdd3de; hoverflow: hidden;}

.panel {
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 130px;  
    position: relative;
    -webkit-perspective: 600px;
    -moz-perspective: 600px;
}

.panel .front,
.panel .back {
    text-align: center;
}

.panel .front {
    height: inherit;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 900;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
       -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
       -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
       -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
       -moz-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
         -o-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
            transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}

.panel .back {
    height: inherit;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
       -moz-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
       -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
       -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
       -moz-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
         -o-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
            transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}
.panel.flip .front {
    z-index: 900;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.panel.flip .back {
    z-index: 1000;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
}
.box1{
    background-color: #14bcc8;
    width: 250px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
}
.box2{
    background-color: #ff7e70;
    width: 250px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
}





$(document).ready(function(){
        // set up hover panels
        // although this can be done without JavaScript, we've attached these events
        // because it causes the hover to be triggered when the element is tapped on a touch device
        $('.hover').hover(function(){
            $(this).addClass('flip');
        },function(){
            $(this).removeClass('flip');
        });
    });
```

Comment: Check http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms3d. IE8 and IE9 not support then after new version partial support.

Comment: Code link goes nowhere.

Comment: Even the link you shared is not working

Answer (score 2):

CSS3 3D Transforms Doesn't support to IE version Upto 8 and 9. And IE version 10 and 11 Partial support.

Partial support menas not supporting the `transform-style: preserve-3d` property. This prevents nesting 3D transformed elements.

[Reference Link.](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms3d)

Comment: @Arhyan will you accept it as a answer.